# Select n rows from a table that has 2 types of choices

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have the following table structure:

```
+----+--------+------+
| id | gender | name |
+----+--------+------+
| 00 |   m    |   A  |
| 01 |   f    |   B  |
| 02 |   m    |   C  |
| 03 |   m    |   D  |
+----+--------+------+
```

From this table I would like to retrieve say 2 male gender names and 1 female gender names. Instead of writing 2 separate queries that will poll the database badly, I want to know if there is a single query that can do the needful. So my resultant JSON shall contain the 2m1f records.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you wants all possible combination? then you have to write procedure

Comment: Basically I want all top ranked people in a department where number of males = 10 and number of females = 10.

Also, there should always be 10 male and 10 female.

Comment: try to use union in the query

Comment: Excellent! Thanks! that worked. But how is the performance compared to writing it as 2 separate SELECT queries?

Comment: @AbhilashLR,dont have any idea about performancs..

Comment: use Union All in the query to increase performance, after that you need to make sure there are no double record in the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i read he comment, you want to get top ranked people in a departement so you would probably have a gade field

Data :

```
id   gender name  grade
---- ------ ----- -----
00   m      Jon   A
01   f      Lin   B
02   m      Kim   C
00   m      Ran   D
```

Use union in the query:

```
select Top 2 id,Name, gender, grade from @temp where gender = 'm' and grade in ('A','B') --Male
union 
select Top 1 id,Name, gender, grade from @temp where gender = 'f' and grade in ('A','B') --female
```

Note: you can change the max row value more dynamically in store procedure.

Result:

```
id   Name  gender grade
---- ----- ------ -----
00   Jon   m      A
01   Lin   f      B
```

Comment: Perfect. Couldn't mark codelover's answer as accepted - Not sure why. But this with code greatly helped! Thanks :)